# PHP Session Variable In JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, session, passwords

How could I input php in this so when it has a correct password it stores the information as a cookie and then allow the deletion to it too.

```
  <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
    <!--hide

    var password;

    var pass1="password";

    password=prompt('Please enter your password to view this page!',' ');

    if (password==pass1){
      alert('Password Correct! Click OK to enter!');}
    else
       {
        window.location="//Some Location//";
        }

    //-->
    </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: You don't need PHP do create a cookie, you can do that from JavaScript. But you do need PHP for authentication. Use JavaScript like that, and your site will be hacked by a 5-year old kid in seconds.

Comment: @bfavaretto 4 year old. I know some smart kids.

Comment: @jeroen, I hope my answer is constructive enough

Comment: @Starx It is, and where the research effort is concerned I guess the downvotes are justified as well...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If its simple enough *(As per the title)*

```
var varname = '<?php echo $_SESSION["variable_name"]; ?>';
```

But you have to seriously consider your logic. You are checking for authentication on javascript, which is going to be *dumbest* move in a web application.

The password is totally exposed, and any one can view them or turn off the javascript as a whole, then your whole site becomes vulnerable.

---

My suggestion is an AJAX request to a PHP page which separately checks and verifies the password and then returns message to the Javascript.

Comment: how would i put it though so its $_SESSION["variable_name"] == pass1

Comment: @user1345650, You cannot do like that, php runs on server and javascript on client's machine

Answer (score 1):

This is completely wrong:

- You will have password displayed in the source code of the page and in the history of the browser for anybody to see. So even if they don't have the password, they can just check the source-code to get it.
- You need to protect the current page **server-side** as anybody that disables javascript can open it now. An easy way to do that, would be to handle the login server-side and set a certain session variable for a successfully logged-in user. You can then check at the top of your page if that session variable is set.

Comment: `//Some location//` seems to be the "access denied" page, not the final destination (which I'm assuming is the current page, accessible by just disabling JavaScript).